# VBA Code modification trouble

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file, path

I have excel file that has a VB code in it that looks like this:

```
Sub UPISIVANJE_IZ_CELIJA_U_FILE()
    Dim iCntr
    Dim strFile_Path As String

    strFile_Path = "C:\script generator v1.1\start.bat"
    Open strFile_Path For Output As #2
    For iCntr = 1 To 10041
        Print #2, Range("E" & iCntr)
    Next iCntr
    Close #2

End Sub
```

Code works without any problems. What I am having trouble with, is the start.bat file location. I want this file to be generated in same location where excel workbook file is. I tried using this:

```
strFile_Path = ".\start.bat"
```

But of course it didn't work.

Comment: Try `strFile_Path = ThisWorkbook.Path + "\start.bat"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you mean the path to the workbook that the code is a part of,

```
strFile_Path = thisworkbook.path & ".\start.bat"
```

Note that VBA uses the ampersand (e.g. `&`) for string concatenation, not the plus sign (e.g. `+`). A plus sign can concatenate strings when it cannot perform addition but the operation is ambiguous and should not be relied upon.

Comment: This works man. Thank for your quick answer and help. If its not too much to ask, how can i make start.bat automaticaly execute at the end.

Comment: I believe it is something like `Shell.Open` but that would be another question. I would  suggest you [close](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this question and start another with the updated information lest this become a [Russian Doll Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625).